# Resolution of omp_get_wtime() in C++

Tags: c++, openmp

What is the time resolution of omp_get_wtime() in C++ on Windows, Linux and MacOSX?

I read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x721b5yk.aspx. It says it returns seconds but nothing about resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP provides the function `omp_get_wtick` which has the effect

> The **omp_get_wtick** routine returns a value equal to the number of
>   seconds between successive clock ticks of the timer used by
>   **omp_get_wtime**.

(*I've taken that from the draft of the OpenMP 4.0 standard, I expect the wording is similar or identical in earlier versions.*)

From that you can compute the precision/resolution available to OpenMP programs on your system(s).

Comment: What do you mean by "the precision that the clock on the platform can provide"? Also, I need to practically "know" or measure what is the resolution.

Comment: omp_get_wtick will give me the MAX resolution possible. I need the MIN, so that I can provide times in ms, microsec or nanosec. Otherwise, ALL methods measuring time would have the same resolution, which is not the case.